# Excel Data is not reading from amazon s3 server

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am uploading the excel file in amazon s3 server and its getting uploaded successfully, but while reading that same excel file in php getting the below data.

```html
����E�    �ɂ^R,5���    I
�ҧ���{ߙw�Ig�FS���셄�0b����[�Jb���k�>+��s��Q�z�� ,E�� º
����u���    ����O�DC�pn��Wi�_��p1F�h��axu���\tWW�N�b��~�:�    >����*���p�1�ڧ 掓�f��Q����PK)��e�PK�;:K
xl/styles.xml�Y[o�0}߯���R�e
�Z�L���j�4i�&�8�Uǎ�B�|    !    ��jT>���%7�l�Q��EA8��A�B���(�xA!�������rF�m�����J�r�"Lq���c�jb.2$UQ$N���B7ʨ�v:GN����&Y���|¤�QA��F
<�A`��<RR�\^]ޜ���9%��Ŝ-x���W<�DIW���rD2� 蘟�ʰ
xl/sharedStrings.xmlPK�;:K)��e��xl/workbook.xmlPK�;:K�,q�^�
Gxl/styles.xmlPK�;:K�!49���docProps/app.xmlPK�;:K�ma�m�docProps/core.xmlPK�;:K�������docProps/custom.xmlPK�;:K�@��C��[Content_Types].xmlPKh
```

using the below php code to print the data

```js
$s3Client->registerStreamWrapper();
     $stream = file_get_contents(utf8_encode($this->stock_catalog_xls_path), 'r');
echo $stream;
```

so please can you give me any idea how to read this excel data in php.

Comment: looks like an excel file to me, what did you expect?

Comment: @rtfm,i except the excel data to be an array format

Comment: excel is not php or js or ... its excel

Comment: @rtfm I have uploaded the file in amazon s3 storage through php  . and i am trying to retrive the data that is stored in the excel. for that i have registered the stream wrapper and i am trying to read the excel contents. but when trying to read the contents i am getting this charaters why ???

Comment: because excel files are a binary format

Comment: @rtfm any idea on how we can read the format and convert it into readable array ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are reading Excel as a raw file.

You need to pass the contents to an Excel library, so you can read them with cells, sheets format.

Below is the library that can help you in converting the raw file to excel readable format.

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel

Sample implementation on how to read Excel file.

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Examples/07reader.php

Hope it helps.